# Replace dots in URL with dash

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, str-replace

i want to raplace dots in url with preg_replace

How can i do it?

The URL is:

http://localhost/../images/

I need it to become:

http://localhost/images/

I try to make it like this:

```
$url = 'http://localhost/../images/';
$final = preg_replace('\/', '/\..\/', $url);
```

I try also like this:

```
$url = 'http://localhost/../images/';
$final = preg_replace('/', '/../', $url);
```

Comment: Where is your code? Have you tried something?

Comment: `str_replace('../' , '' , $string);` would do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `preg_replace` usage is incorrect, but you don't need a regex for this anyway. For static replacements just use `str_replace`.

```
$url = 'http://localhost/../images/';
$url = str_replace('..', '', $url);
```

but your probably also should include the `/` in the search.

Your `preg_replace` is inverted the pattern is the first parameter and the replacement value second. http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

So the correct `preg_replace` would be:

```
$url = 'http://localhost/../images/';
$final = preg_replace('/\.\./', '/', $url);
```

Also this is putting a third `/` between the domain and directory. The `/`s are [delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) in the pattern, did you mean for that?

Note the `.`s are special characters and need to be escaped.